# File Permission problems with a Linux VM - unable to read file

Tags: permissions, virtual-machine

I have built a Rocky Linux (9.1) Virtual machine, and I am having permission problems with some of the files. Note also (after looking at the linked 'similar questions'), this is a local mount, not NFS or anything remote.

The anonymised permissions for the files are this:
`-r--r--r--. 1 engineer myadmin <filesize> <date> filename.jar`

For the SE Linux context:
`unconfined_u:object_r:defailt_t:s0 filename.jar`

Running `id` for the user provides this output:
`uid=1001(engineer) gid=1002(myadmin) groups=1002(myadmin),1001(engineer) context=unconfirmed_u:unconfirmed_r_unconfirmed_t:s0`

Any attempt to read the file is met with:
`cannot open 'filename.jar' for reading: Operation not permitted`

I have tried looking at file permissions, mount options, SE Linux permissions, and user groups. I expect that the user `engineer` should be able to read the file.

Mount options for the drive are:
`rw,seclabel,relatime`

All attempts to read files result in `Operation not permitted`.

What am I missing?

---

Additional info, as requested in a comment:

The results from `journalctl -n 100` are:

```
<timestamp> <hostname> login[<pid>]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user engineer(uid=1001) by engineer(uid=0)
<timestamp> <hostname> login[<pid>]: LOGIN ON pts/1 BY engineer
```

`dmesg` provides no information regarding attempts to open files.

SE Linux is present, but is in `permissive` mode, so shouldn't be restricting anything anyway.

Comment: "Operation not permitted" (as opposed to "Permission denied") indicates something along the lines of MAC denial (SELinux or AppArmor); can you check `dmesg` or `journalctl -n 100` to see if it has logged any audit errors?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I have added more details to the question, specifically the output of `journalctl` (`dmesg` provided nothing of use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't `selinux` preventing access, but `fapolicyd`. Specifically, it was a rule which specified `deny_audit perm=any all: ftype=application/java-archive`

Solution:

- `systemctl stop fapolicyd` (to disable the file access policy from applying)
- run `fapolicyd --debug-deny` (to show access which is disallowed)
- attempt to open a file which previously indicated `Operation not permitted`
- observe which rule it violates
- carefully read the manpage for `fapolicy.rules(5)`, and construct a new rule file allowing the group or user to open java archives (`.jar` files), and also java applets (`.class` files)
- run `fagenrules --load` to install the newly created rule
- stop and restart `fapolicy --debug-deny`
- attempt to open the same file as above, and actually open it (with no logged rule)
- cheer, or fist-pump, to indicate that I know how to fix my problems (this step is optional)
- restart `fapolicyd` with the command `systemctl enable --now fapolicyd`